# How to fade out a div using getTime,Date() timer after exactly 24 hours?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, gettime

```
<div class="ml-2">Time Remaining&emsp;<span id="remainingTime">24:00:00</span></div>

<div class="row" id="offer1" style="margin-top: -7%;">asdf</div>

<script>
setTimeout(function () {
  $('#offer1').fadeOut('fast');
  $('#remainingTime').fadeOut('fast');
}, 8640000);

function Timer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
      hours, 
      minutes,
      seconds;

  setInterval(function () {
    hours = parseInt((timer / 3600) % 24, 10);
    minutes = parseInt((timer / 60) % 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);;

    hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.text(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);

    --timer;
  }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
  var twentyFourHours = 24 * 60 * 60;
  var display = $('#remainingTime');
  Timer(twentyFourHours, display);
});
</script>
```

How to fade out an element using Date(),GetTime()? For example I've set the timer here for 24 hours. Even if the browser refreshes or tab closes or device turned off, timer should be running. And after 24 Hours exactly, the div should fade out and here's the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Manoj07/emq30y2o/5/

Comment: You can't run a timer if the browser is closed. Instead, in a `load` event handler, check to see if a "startTime" entry has already been made in `localStorage`. If so, create a new `Date` using that time and then compare that time to the current time. If 24 hours has already elapsed, fade the element out, if not, start a new timer and set the initial page load time in `localStorage`.

Comment: You can't guarantee that a timer using *setInterval* will run at exactly the set time, it will drift. So setting it to 1 second and running it 8.64e4 times will almost certainly not be *exactly* 24 hours. Also, not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed.